# Why is visual C++ giving me this error?

Tags: c++, enums

So I don't know why I'm getting this error saying "Error:Argument of type "color" is not compatible with parameter of type "color(*)[2]"" at the line I marked

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum color{black, white};

bool negative(color a[2][2], color b[2][2]);
void main(){

color a[2][2] = { { black, white }, { white, black } };
color b[2][2] = { { white, black }, { black, white } };
negative(a[2][2], b[2][2]);  //<==== here (under "a" and "b")

}

bool negative(color a[2][2], color b[2][2]){
int False=0, True=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        if (a[i][j] != b[i][j]) True++;
        else False++;
    }
}
    if (True == 2 && False == 0)return true;
    else if (True == 0 && False == 2)return false;

}
```

Comment: please, please, please write a better title. I simply normally skip over questions that are this nondescriptively titled.

Comment: Call your function like this: `negative(a, b);`

Answer (score 0):

The `negative` function accepts array of arrays of `color` arguments, but you pass a *single* `color` value, one that is from beyond the range of the arrays as well.

Call as

```
negative(a, b);
```

I suggest you go back to your book or tutorial and read more about arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you should be passing an array, but instead you're trying to pass an element (that doesn't even exist).

When you do

`a[2][2]` you describe the third row, third column (if you think of your 2d array as table) element of the array.

```
 negative(a,b)
```

is what you probably want to do.